# How to create Mega menu in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, megamenu

how to create a custom `mega menu`  in **magento 1.x**
like below image

[image]

Comment: i have created same menu but not view more functionality added

Comment: can u explain me how to create a mega menu @rakesh

Comment: check my answer and create custom menu template file and add this code

Comment: how could i create a custom menu template @rakesh

Comment: you can default menu commented and custom menu create below way create custom phtml file and call in header file

Answer (score 1):

This code working and i have tested also you can just "**carparts**" category hover below ul show and then working code

```
<ul class="all-category-list" role="menu">
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
    ?>
            <li>
                <a class="d-block text-black px-3 py-3 position-relative" href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?><i class="fa fa-arrow-right font-size-10 text-pink mr-3 position-absolute rightside-arrow"></i></a>
                <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
                <?php if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                    <ul class="sub-category position-absolute animated fadeInLeft">

                        <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                            <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                            <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>
                            <li> <?php
                                    $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                    echo '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . ' class="d-block text-black px-2 py-1 font-weight-medium font-size-15 my-3 mx-3">' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '</a>';
                                ?>

                            <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                              <ul class="child-sub-category my-3 mx-3">
                                <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                    <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php
                                            $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                            echo '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . ' class="d-block text-black px-2 py-1">' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '</a>';
                                        ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count() >4): ?>
                                    <a href=""><?php echo $this->__("..View More")?></a>
                                 <?php ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: In my case, I can solve it by jQuery functions i was upvoted your answer it will help me for future reference  @rakesh